# Should SQLConnection from ReliableSqlConnection be closed?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

Every example I have found on using `ReliableSqlConnection` looks similar to:

```
using (var cnn = new ReliableSqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cnn.Open();
        ...
    }
}
```

As `Open()` returns a `SQLConnection` which is `IDisposable`, shouldn't it be disposed?

Would it make any difference or harm, if I encapsulate in a using statement?

```
using (var cnn = new ReliableSqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
        using(cnn.Open(){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to dispose, the **deprecated** `ReliableSQLConnection` class creates the `SqlConnection` in its ctor and disposes of it in its `Dispose()`:

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (this.underlyingConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this.underlyingConnection.Close();
        }

        this.underlyingConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where did you find the source code for that?
I did find it on [projky.com](http://www.projky.com/entlib/6.0/Microsoft/Practices/EnterpriseLibrary/TransientFaultHandling/ReliableSqlConnection.cs.html) but that does not look as an official ressource. 

Do you know why `ReliableSQLConnection::Dispose()` calls `SQLConnection::Close()`? 
As far as I know `SQLConnection::Dispose()` calls `SQLConnection::Close()`

Comment: It was on my machine as part of the EnterpriseLibrary.Source.WindowsAzure nuget package

Comment: Calling close is not needed as you say, the fact they do is probably a stylistic choice.